# Moving AD between two 2008 R2

Tags: windows, active-directory, migration

I need to do a fresh install of 2008 R2 Standard and migrate my current AD DB to it. Is there a way to backup the whole DB and restore it after installation ? I cannot transfer it 'online' cause i will be using the same rack server FROM and TO.

We have a few issues with Microsoft licensing and i need to reinstall every 2008 R2 Enterprise as Standard, you can imagine how screwed i am.

Its not a huge database, about 150 users and a few small OUs/GPOs.

Best regaards

Answer (score 2):

Would you be able to temporarily have an "intermediate server" where you could migrate to?

Then Scott Vickrey's approach would work, you would just have to migrate it twice (once to the "intermediate" server, and then, after re-installation, to the destination machine)

Comment: Ideally you could keep a second one on-line permanently to provide some redudancy.

Comment: +1.  This is the *only* way it can be done safely.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, join the new server to the current domain, perform a DCPROMO of the server, allow time for replication then move all the FSMO roles to the new server. Afterwards, DCPROMO the old server to remove its DC role.

Comment: He said he cannot do it online... :)